# Explicit generator return type in TypeScript demands that `Generator.prototype.return` takes a parameter

Tags: typescript, generator

I have a generator function acting as a consumer to accumulate strings:

```js
function *concatStrings(): Generator<void, string, string> {
  let result = '';
  try {
    while (true) {
      const data = yield;
      result += data;
    }
  } finally {
    return result;
  }
}

const g = concatStrings();
g.next();
g.next('abc');
const r = g.return();
console.log(r);
```

This works fine, but in TS, it complains

```
Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.ts(2554)
lib.es2015.generator.d.ts(26, 12): An argument for 'value' was not provided.
```

[Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAKggiBDKBlKAnGMAcwGcAKASgC5EBxAUzHryzjwB4A3OGAEwBpEJfISKDhBYgD5EAbwCwAKESIANvSiI89EiFWaAvIgDkxgNxKV+AJ5zLKxAHcAFjHWIy+EPQp3lDlTQwYUReLAxEI2sYelVeC38A7V19RABqIzCoDASAgF97PMRgQgxVVVsFRK0NEDwkZL0oXMQCxTalIJCiSMQgzBwRYnIKBKIAOiYADyhKMcn6GbJjDAAjCGNRzoQQvF6J7Sg6sDnt4Lh1cdU4IjI8UaA)

How do I create a version of the top that TS doesn't complain, but I also end up with the right types?

Comment: This will work, although you will get a result where `void` is aprt of the value, which is not ideal https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAKggiBDKBlKAnGMAcwGcAKASgC5EBxAUzHryzjwB4A3OGAEwBpEJfISKIAPom59BwgsQB8iAN4BYAFCJEAG3pREeeiRDb9AXkQBySwG4NW-AE8V9rYgDuACxi7EZfCD0FC6ablpoYCRwugB02nBEZABEADJwcAAOSRSuYRHCiLxYGIgWjjD02rx2oWGGxqaIANQWRVAYNWEAvq5diMCEGNrazmq1iPnR9HEJyQDCuhhgIFk544ZQIHhI9SZQnYg96kca+fpiFhGYOCLE5BQ1RDFMAB5QlI-P9G9klhgARhBLA9TggCnhSognhstmAPohQZEpjNEngYpwhoEHkA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're *overriding* the usual mechanism of the `return` method by using a `return` statement in a `finally` block that throws away the value provided to the method and returns `result` instead. That's why the signature doesn't match up. In the normal case, the parameter value of the `return` method is also the `TReturn` of the generator ([example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAKggiBDKBlKAnGMAcwGcAKASgC5EBxAUzHryzjwB4T9CiAaRLgWL9BPAHyIA3gFgAUIgWIANvSiI89EiCVqAvIgDkBgNxzFiAO4ALGCsRl8IehSlnzitGC6IAJlgyI+gCeMPRKPuqa2lCm8u4KGlo6iADU+n5QGLHmAL5yebJynt5EgYiemDjcxOQUsSpqeDQAklDMrHgASlE6nNV8Av1isUQAdEwAHlCUsXhlY5PTAEQYS3VFCCRwKqNKcERkeKMAbhhKTuuyc-pjGlAgeGBkS1A2JIgw72BsALZnSkFEK96IhgGwIPQIolomtYsVtvRdvtDiczhdYkA)). From MDN:

> **`Generator.prototype.return()`**
>
> Acts as if a `return` statement is inserted in the generator's body at the current suspended position, which finishes the generator and allows the generator to perform any cleanup tasks when combined with a `try`...`finally` block.

*(Cleanup tasks don't usually include a `return` statement.)*

For what it's worth, I'd encourage you to define and use your generator slightly differently — just use the result of `next`, no need for that final `return`, like this:

```typescript
function *concatStrings(): Generator<string, void, string> {
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^
    let result = '';
    // (Note no `try`/`finally`, since you don't have resources to clean up)
    while (true) {
        const data = yield result;
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^
        result += data;
    }
}

const g = concatStrings();
let r: IteratorResult<string, void>;
g.next();
r = g.next("a");
console.log(r.value); // "a"
r = g.next("b");
console.log(r.value); // "ab"
r = g.next("c");
console.log(r.value); // "abc"
```

[Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAKggiBDKBlKAnGMAcwGcAKASgC5EBxAUzHryzjwB4T9CiAaRAG5wYAE35cCxAHyIA3gFgAUIhWIANvSiI89EiDVaAvIgDkJgNxLViAO4ALGBsRl8IehTlXrqtGC6IRLAxEYwBPGHo1EW1dfShLZW8VHT0DRABqY0CoDATrAF8lQsUlX38iEMRfTBxuYnIKBI0tPBoASShmVjwAJViDTjq+QWERKQSiADomAA8oSgS8SqnZ+YAiDDXG0oQSOA1JtTgiMjxJgQw1N23FJeMV+jmyNYAjLYSy-fpD49Pzy+ui2W00e6wg7x2fi+PxOZwuV3cCSAA)

This also solves the type problem, because we're no longer going off the standard path. :-)

Comment: The example given is actually a simplified version of a hashing generator. It can't actually return intermediate results.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai - Ah. In that case, I'd lean toward a flag value w/`next` vs `return` ([example](https://tsplay.dev/m0nzPw)). It's just that the `return` method has specific semantics, and that generator is violating them. (At least, that's how it seems to me... :-) )

Comment: The next with flag is very similar to @titian-cernicova-dragomir's second solution in syntax in terms of doing `return(null!)` vs `next(null)`. On the other hand, your `next(null)` solution does appear to require the least amount of assertions involving `!`.

Comment: I'm going to mark your comment as the solution actually. Since I think it is the most idiomatic. https://tsplay.dev/m0nzPw

Answer (score 1):

The `return` method is defined as requiring a parameter. If a parameter type is `void` it does not have to be passed in. We can specify the return type as `string | void`. This will allow us to not specify the return type:

```
function *concatStrings(): Generator<void, string | void, string> {
  let result = '';
  try {
    while (true) {
      console.log("Loop")
      const data = yield;
      result += data;
    }
  } finally {
    console.log("Cleanup")
    return result;
  }
}

const g = concatStrings();
g.next();
g.next('abc');
const r = g.return();  
if(typeof r.value ===  "string")  {
  console.log(r.value);
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAKggiBDKBlKAnGMAcwGcAKASgC5EBxAUzHryzjwB4A3OGAEwBpEJfISKIAPom59BwgsQB8iAN4BYAFCJEAG3pREeeiRDb9AXkQBySwG4NW-AE8V9rYgDuACxi7EZfCD0FC6ablpoYCRwugB02nBEZABEADJwcAAOSRSuYRHCiLxYGIgWjjD02rx2oWGGxqaIANQWRVAYNWEAvq5diMCEGNrazmq1iPnR9HEJyQDCuhhgIFk544ZQIHhI9SZQnYg96kca+fpiFhGYOCLE5BQ1RDFMAB5QlI-P9G9klhgARhBLA9TggCnhSognhstmAPloNDBgP5HBl6HBgAYYpwhoFSmYLIgknJRNktGNwmCpjNEnhsbigjUukA)

This will mean that `r.value` will be `void | string, which is less than ideal` so you will need to check for `string` before you can use it.

Another option is to pass in `null!` as an argument to return `g.return(null!);` ([Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAKggiBDKBlKAnGMAcwGcAKASgC5EBxAUzHryzjwB4A3OGAEwBpEJfISKDhBYgD5EAbwCwAKESIANvSiI89EiFWaAvIgDkxgNxKV+AJ5zLKxAHcAFjHWIy+EPQp3lDlTQwYUReLAxEI2sYelVeC38A7V19RABqIzCoDASAgF97PMRgQgxVVVsFRK0NEDwkZL0oXMQCxTalIJCiSMQgzBwRYnIKBKIAOiYADyhKMcn6GbJjDAAjCGNRzoQQvF6J7Sg6sDIwPVUAQi3FLrh1cdU4IjI8UaA))